# How to add header and footer txt file in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to add a header and footer inside of my text file. How can i do that?  My target should like This:

```
 tr.AddHeaderAndFooter("Header","footer";
```

For example:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TargetDir"] + swiftFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileStream);
    tr.AddHeaderAndFooter("Header","footer";
}
```

Comment: a plain text file doesn't have a header and a footer.

Comment: A header and a footer are both like any other line of text in a text file, except that a header is the first line and a footer is the last line.

Comment: You can't _write_ to a `TextReader`. Also you'll need `FileAccess.ReadWrite` access to the file.

Comment: @DanielA.White Actually in most ETL situations plain text files do have headers and footers.

Comment: @DanielA.White Extract Transform Load, it is development that targets data movement.

Comment: Headers and footers imply _paging_. In a text file, they are just the first line and the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .txt file does not have a header or footer. 
But you can simulate this behaviour with the following code sample:

```
// since there is no predefined method to add a string into the beginning   
// of a file, you have to first read the whole file content into a temporary 
// variable
string currentContent = String.Empty;
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    currentContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}

// now you can put your header into the beginning of the file so:
string header = "My Header";
File.WriteAllText(filePath, header + Environment.NewLine + currentContent );

// and finally you use the append method to add footer to the end of the file
string footer = "My Footer";
File.AppendAllText(filepath, Environment.NewLine + footer);
```

Comment: Great code answer. Can you add some comments to explain to others that might reference this answer in the future?

Comment: Assuming the text file isn't several MB in length, this is as good an answer as any.

Comment: What's about ***Encoding*** ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something along the lines of:

```
string text = "header" + Environment.NewLine + "rest of file ... asjdhakjdh" + Environment.NewLine + "footer";
File.WriteAllText("filename.txt", text);
```

This will save

> header
>
> rest of file ... asjdhakjdh
>
> footer

in a *.txt* file named *filename.txt*

So you could read your file, store it in a string, add your header and footer line and write it back to the same file it came from.

Comment: Just a tip; instead of \n, it's better to use the constant Environment.NewLine for these kinds of things :)